# Как добиться такого наложения на картинку с помощью CSS3 кода?

Tags: css3, wordpress, css

Делаю сайт на Wordpress с использованием темы Enfold. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой элемент Enfold или CSS3 код я должен использовать, чтобы добиться такого наложения на изображения?

[image]

Comment: картинка не открывается.

Comment: @Crus сейчас все ок с картинкой!

Comment: Имеется ввиду синяя ленточка с белым текстом на ней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал через 2 дива:

Первый див с повторяющей линией в 1 пиксель, и хвостик.

Все это, естественно, в общем контейнере.